# What is the difference between a managed and unmanaged switch?

Tags: networking, switch

I've seen some documentation discussing the use of an unmanaged switch. What is the difference in functionality/performance/etc. between an unmanaged and managed switch?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Unmanaged switches — These switches have no configuration interface or options. They are plug-and-play. They are typically the least expensive switches, found in home, SOHO, or small businesses. They can be desktop or rack mounted.

Managed switches — These switches have one or more ways, or interfaces, to modify the operation of the switch. Common management methods include: a serial console or Command Line Interface accessed via telnet or Secure Shell; an embedded Simple Network Management Protocol SNMP agent allowing management from a remote console or management station; a web interface for management from a web browser. Examples of configuration changes that one can do from a managed switch include: enable features such as Spanning Tree Protocol; set port speed; create or modify VLANs, etc.

Two sub-classes of managed switches are marketed today:

Smart (or intelligent) switches — These are managed switches with a limited set of management features. Likewise "web-managed" switches are switches which fall in a market niche between unmanaged and managed. For a price much lower than a fully managed switch they provide a web interface (and usually no CLI access) and allow configuration of basic settings, such as VLANs, port-speed and duplex.[10]

Enterprise Managed (or fully managed) switches - These have a full set of management features, including Command Line Interface, SNMP agent, and web interface. They may have additional features to manipulate configurations, such as the ability to display, modify, backup and restore configurations. Compared with smart switches, enterprise switches have more features that can be customized or optimized, and are generally more expensive than "smart" switches. Enterprise switches are typically found in networks with larger number of switches and connections, where centralized management is a significant savings in administrative time and effort. A Stackable switch is a version of enterprise-managed switch.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch

I would explain in more personal detail, but the wiki explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 20):

Most managed switches offer you features like:

- View the bridging table to see which MAC addresses are associated with a given port
- View error statistics for each port
- View packet transmit / receive statistics for each port
- Set duplex / speed negotiation (or lack thereof) on a per-port basis
- View power-over-Ethernet status and current draw for each port (if applicable)

Typically there is a TELNET, serial, and / or web-based interface to interact with the switch.

Many managed switches allow you to poll the device with the SNMP protocol to use the information described above in graphs, alerts, etc. (Beware-- some low end managed switches, like the Dell 27xx series, don't have SNMP functionality!)

Most managed switches today support things like 802.1D spanning tree, 802.1q VLANs, and 802.3ad link aggregation, and the management interface allows you to configure these various features. You can typically setup port VLAN memberships, link aggregation groups, and control spanning tree parameters all from a web or command-line interface.

A goodly number of managed switches have taken to emulating the Cisco command-line interface (HP ProCurve, Dell PowerConnect to name a couple) such that someone with Cisco-specific knowledge can easily configure those switches.

Answer (score 8):

If you are debating whether it is worth it to upgrading to managed switches, here are some criteria:

- **Security.** Do you need the ability to
  switch on and off ports, match ports
  with MAC addresses, and set up VLANS?
- **Performance.** Do you need to monitor
  and shape traffic of individual ports
  or switches? Do your clients have
  real-time performance needs (SLA's or
  metrics that you must meet)? Do you
  have VOIP set up and want better QoS
  features on the local network?
- **Management.** Would you like the
  ability to be able to easily see
  network performance across various
  clients? Have extra assistance with
  troubleshooting connectivity or other
  issues? Integrate your switches into
  your SNMP management tool for log
  file correlation?
- **Random Features.** Do you have the need
  for link aggregation or the other
  random features offered only by
  managed switches?

Answer (score 5):

One additional thing: Most managed switches allow some form of port binding (so that you can use multiple NICs in a device to effectively multiply the bandwidth to the switch. Also, VLAN support is often not found on unmanaged switches, but are common on managed ones.

Answer (score 3):

Unmanaged switches have a set behavior that works from the time they're powered on until they're powered off.

Managed switches normally have settings that can be modified remotely. This might include turning ports on or off, managing port speeds, throttling, segmenting and more.

Comment: (unmanaged switches)... or until they break.

Answer (score -1):

**Unmanaged** switches are basic plug-and-play switches with no remote configuration, management, or monitoring options, although many can be locally monitored and configured via LED indicators and DIP switches. These inexpensive switches are typically used in small networks or to add temporary workgroups to larger networks.

**Managed switches** support Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) via embedded agents and have a command line interface (CLI) that can be accessed via serial console, Telnet, and Secure Shell. These switches can often be configured and managed as groups. More recent managed switches may also support a Web interface for management through a Web browser.

Comment: This question has already been answered many times. Your answer does not provide extra value.